# how to see current version of iphone SDK in MAC system?

Tags: iphone

anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the command-prompt:

```
xcodebuild -showsdks
```

Answer (score 1):

Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs

Or directly in xcode in the upper left corner?